# {singular} "Со всей этой историей с ..." vs. {plural} "Со всеми этими историями с ..."

Tags: грамматика

> Со **всей этой историей** с допингами, ...
>
> {or}: Со **всеми этими историями** с допингами, ...

I wonder if it is more common in Russian to use a singular construction with this "история" expression. If so, what is the rationale for using the singular? In French, you express the same idea in the plural:

> {plural}: Avec **toutes ces histoires** de dopage, ...
>
> {not singular}: Avec **toute cette histoire** de dopage, ...

Comment: consider the English **affair** - *With this whole doping affair* but really the choice depends on the speaker's idea, whether they refer to multiple individual cases or to the entire scandal... and if speaking of many cases i personally would use **допинг** in singular, just because all words in plural make the phrase cumbersome and **допинг** in this instance means the overarching phenomenon instead of each and every case of it

Answer (score 1):

I do not feel like using "история" or "истории" changes the overall feeling of the sentence. It just depends on whether there was only one "story" or a couple.

I would like to note that истор**иями** с доп**ингами** makes the sentence heavy and more difficult to pronounce. That is why the first option is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no difference between plural and singular forms of the sentences like that. However, in some contexts (sic!), the use of the plural can reduce the importance of the subject. This can be explained as follows: "history" is unique (and significant...); if there are many "histories", they are likely routine and should not be significant. "Истории" sometimes means "случаи", "обыденные ситуации" and so on, up to "байки", "сплетни"... However, sometimes (mostly infrequently), the singular word "история" can be used in a figurative sense like "россказни" and so on.